# jqGrid and Fancybox - Substitute cell contents with 'Open' or 'View'

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, fancybox

I am using jqGrid with Fancybox.  The cell values vary between lengthy text, tabular data or images, hence Fancybox.

I want to substitute the contents of the cell, say 'diagnosis', with something like 'View' or 'Open' which Fancybox then displays the cellvalue.  **The Fancybox display of cellvalue works fine.  Just need help with substituting the cell contents...**

```
          colModel: [
                     {name:"consultation"},
                     {name:"diagnosis",formatter:fancyBoxFormatter},
                     {name:"prescription",formatter:fancyBoxFormatter}, 
                     {name:"tests",formatter:fancyBoxFormatter},
                     {name:"imaging",formatter:fancyBoxFormatter},
                     {name:"generic",formatter:fancyBoxFormatter},
                     {name:"referral",formatter:fancyBoxFormatter},
                     {name:"management",formatter:fancyBoxFormatter},
                     {name:"completed"}
                         ],
```

And Fancybox custom formatter (thanks Oleg for getting this working!):

```
function fancyBoxFormatter (cellvalue, options) {
    return "<a class=\"fancybox\" href=\"#data" +
        options.rowId + "_" + options.colModel.name + "\">" + cellvalue + "</a>" +
        "<div style=\"display:none\"><div id=\"data" +
        options.rowId + "_" + options.colModel.name + "\">" +
        cellvalue + "</div></div>";
}
```

Comment: Please share **the demo**, which can be used to reproduce the problem. I personally don't use Fancybox and I don't understand what you mean under "substituting the cell contents". I'm not sure that I correctly understand what you need. Probably you want to use custom buttons of `formatter: "actions"`. Look at the first demos included on [the page](//free-jqgrid.github.io/examples/index.html): [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/CustomActionButton.htm) and [this one](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/CustomActionButton1.htm)

Comment: This is the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44384520/jqgrid-with-fancybox-get-cell-object/44404393?noredirect=1#comment75809529_44404393

Comment: So instead of displaying the cellvalue in the cell, I would like to display the word 'View', as the cellvalue will always be too big to display in the cell in its entirety.  Clicking on View in the cell will display the cellvalue in the fancybox dialogue as per the demo on the previous answer