# JqGrid with Fancybox - get cell object

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, fancybox

Using the follow in `jqGrid`:

```
 colModel: [
            {name:"",index:"",width:100},
            {name:"diagnosis",index:"diagnosis",width:100,formatter:fancyBoxFormatter},
            {name:"prescription", index:"prescription",width:100,formatter:fancyBoxFormatter}, 
            {name:"tests",index:"tests",width:100,formatter:fancyBoxFormatter},
            {name:"imaging",index:"imaging",width:100,formatter:fancyBoxFormatter},
            {name:"generic",index:"generic",width:100,formatter:fancyBoxFormatter},
            {name:"referral",index:"referral",width:100,formatter:fancyBoxFormatter},
            {name:"management",index:"management",width:100,formatter:fancyBoxFormatter},
            {name:"completed",index:"completed",width:100}
            ],
```

Then:

```
function fancyBoxFormatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {

    var result,
        link,
        fancyBoxHTML,
        fancyBoxContent;

    link = "<a class=\"fancybox\" href=\"#data" + options.rowId + "\">" + cellvalue + "</a>";
    fancyBoxContent = cellvalue;
    fancyBoxHTML = "<div style=\"display:none\"><div id=\"data" + options.rowId + "\">" + fancyBoxContent + "</div></div>";
    return link + fancyBoxHTML;
}
```

This displays the same content in Fancybox for all cells in the row (based on rowID...)  How can I change this function to individual cell IDs, rather than just the whole row?

Comment: Could you post more jqGrid details? Which **version** of jqGrid you use? Which **fork** of jqGrid you use ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)? In any way you use wrong value `name:""` for the forst column and the formatter `fancyBoxFormatter` generate divs with id duplicates, because you use the same `id` (`"data" + options.rowId`) for all columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please write in all questions about jqGrid the **version** of jqGrid, which you use (can use) and the **fork** which you use ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7).

The `options` parameter of the custom formatter `fancyBoxFormatter` contains `rowId`, `colModel`, `gid`, `pos` and `rowData` properties (`rowData` exists only in free jqGrid fork). Thus you can use, for example,

```
function fancyBoxFormatter (cellvalue, options) {
    return "<a class=\"fancybox\" href=\"#data" +
        options.rowId + "_" + options.colModel.name + "\">" + cellvalue + "</a>" +
        "<div style=\"display:none\"><div id=\"data" +
        options.rowId + "_" + options.colModel.name + "\">" +
        cellvalue + "</div></div>";
}
```

Additionally you have to fix the `name` property of the first column. One can't use empty `name` (see `name:""`). You could use *any* unique value for `name` holding the rules existing in HTML5/CSS for ids (for example no spaces).

I'd recommend you additionally to remove unneeded `index` properties and common `width:100` option from all columns. Instead of placing `width:100` in every column you can use `cmTemplate: {width: 100}` option of jqGrid.

Comment: Hi Oleg, I am using Guriddo jqGrid JS 5.2.1 as a trial

Comment: I have replaced the fancybox function with your code without any changes and put in a name for the first column.  I'm now getting inside fancybox display "The requested content cannot be loaded. Please try again later."

Comment: @IlludiumPu36: Please, share **the demo** (as JSFiddle, for example), which reproduces the problem. I fixed the code posted in my answer, because one probably have to change `href` value if the `id` is changed. By the way, I develop [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/) fork of jqGrid, which is available completely free of charge under MIT or GPLv2 licenses,  and will be not able to help you with Guriddo specific problems.

Comment: That change seems to have fixed it!  Many thanks indeed.  Link to updated page is http://130.95.21.121/vmd/evaluation/evaluation_2.php  On the cohort menu select 'All-Staf' then click the linked ID that shows to bring up the grid.

Comment: What is the difference from your free version and the Guriddo version?  Probably not after a complete list, but does your version have subgrids and the ability to have multiple subgrids at the same level?  You can see the basic functionality I'm after in the link above.  So there would be three consultation subgrids for a case...

Comment: @IlludiumPu36: Sorry, but the demo http://130.95.21.121/vmd/evaluation/evaluation_2.php displays no grid: only one dropdown. "jqGrid" not exist since the end of 2014. The last version of jqGrid was 4.7. After that Tony Tomov published [the post](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?p=1438), where he announced renaming of the project, which he develop to "Guriddo jqGrid", changing the license agreement and making the product commercial (see the prices [here](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334)). jqGrid 4.7 was the last version available under MIT/GPL. MIT/GPL allows to make new **fork** and develop it.

Comment: @IlludiumPu36: I implemented a lot of bug fixes, rewrote large part of old code holding backward compatibility, improved performance and implemented many new features. See [the wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki), [here](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html) and README to all previously published free jqGrid versions (from 4.8 till 4.14.1). Look at [the link](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/compare/v4.7.0...master). You will see that there are **1634 commits** between jqGrid 4.7 and free jqGrid 4.14.1. It means that internal code in very different now.

Comment: Thanks I'll make the switch.  On the dropdown menu select 'All-Staf' then click the linked ID that shows to bring up the grid.

Comment: @IlludiumPu36: "The demo" don't display any fancyBox. It fills subgrid with empty data displayed as "undefined". The code of `fancyBoxFormatter` is still old, which generate id duplicates. Moreover you don't use `idPrefix` in subgrid (for example `idPrefix: row_id + "_"`), thus you could have additional id duplicates. One more problem: you create jqGrid inside of `success` of Ajax request. It converts empty `<table id="grid"></table>` i complex structure of divs and tables. It works **only once**. Later choosing of another option (`IMED4111`, for example) will be ignored.

Comment: @IlludiumPu36: You can add call of `GridUnload` before creating of the grid or to use of `reloadGrid` instead of recreating of the grid. Additional remarks: you use XML as the input (which contains wrong values too: see `<page></page><total></total><records></records>`), which is not recommended. It's better to use JSON data. Additionally it's good to use more recent versions of jQuery and Fancybox. Your demo uses retro versions of all dependent products.

Comment: OK thanks for the tips Oleg, I'll look at these during the switch to your free version.  BTW, I looked at https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid and at https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html but could not find any examples of bringing data in from a database and the format to use...

Comment: @IlludiumPu36: Sorry, but you should describe more detailed what you need to implement. You current code use **server side** paging and sorting of data. Is it what you really need? How many total rows could be in the grid/subgrid (10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000000)? The format of input data depend on the answer on the question. What kind of information you need to display? Do you want to use Fancybox to display pictures or texts?

Comment: @IlludiumPu36: The simple modification of the first demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/3ddnkvow/ from https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html would be the following https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/cL836sbm/. It uses Echo service of JSFiddle, which allows to simulate any server response. The standard demo would just return the array of items as JSON data as response on `url`. `postData: { json: JSON.stringify(serverResponse) }` be used to *send* to echo service the data, which it returns immediately.

Comment: Hi Oleg The data that needs to be displayed already exists in a MySQL database, the grid is used to evaluate that data.  So with the Guriddo version, i have been using, for example, url: "scripts/get_user_current_case.php?user="+user, to get the data in XML...does the free version support similar, albeit JSON?

Comment: @IlludiumPu36: Yes you can use the same XML data with free jqGrid, but JSON is more recommended as XML. You can replace URLs to Guriddo jqGrid JS to URLs to free jqGrid (see [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs)) and your current code will display the same results.